# Changing background color of bootstrap/css page

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am using a bootstrap template and I am a beginner.
I want to change the backgroud blue color into a color of my choice.
I also want to change the color of the button.

I tried playing around with CSS files, but i failed.

main.css :

```
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ FONT ]*/

@font-face {
 font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
 src: url('../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'); 
}

@font-face {
 font-family: Montserrat-ExtraBold;
 src: url('../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-ExtraBold.ttf'); 
}

@font-face {
 font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
 src: url('../fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf'); 
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ RESTYLE TAG ]*/

* {
   margin: 0px; 
   padding: 0px; 
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
   height: 100%;
   font-family: Montserrat-Regular, sans-serif;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
a {
   font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.7;
   color: #666666;
   margin: 0px;
   transition: all 0.4s;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
}

a:focus {
   outline: none !important;
}

a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
   margin: 0px;
}

p {
   font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.7;
   color: #666666;
   margin: 0px;
}

ul, li {
   margin: 0px;
   list-style-type: none;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
input {
   outline: none;
   border: none;
}

textarea {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
 border-color: transparent !important;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #999999; }
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #999999; }

/*---------------------------------------------*/
button {
   outline: none !important;
   border: none;
   background: transparent;
}

button:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}

iframe {
   border: none !important;
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ Utility ]*/
.txt1 {
 font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #cccccc;
 line-height: 1.4;
}

.bo1 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
}

.hov1:hover {
 border-color: #d33f8d;
}


/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ login ]*/

.limiter {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container-login100 {
 width: 100%;  
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 15px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;

 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.container-login100::before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #005bea;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 background: linear-gradient(bottom, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 opacity: 0.9;
}

.wrap-login100 {
 width: 390px;
 background: transparent;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[  ]*/
.login100-form {
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.login100-form-title {
 font-family: Montserrat-ExtraBold;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1.2;
 text-align: center;

 width: 100%;
 display: block;
}

/*---------------------------------------------*/
.login100-form-avatar {
 width: 120px;
 height: 120px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.login100-form-avatar img {
 width: 100%;
}


/*---------------------------------------------*/
.wrap-input100 {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
}

.input100 {
 font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1.2;
 color: #333333;

 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 padding: 0 30px 0 53px;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Focus ]*/
.focus-input100 {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 25px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(0,91,234, 0.6);
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100 {
 -webkit-animation: anim-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
 animation: anim-shadow 0.5s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-shadow {
 to {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px 30px;
   opacity: 0;
 }
}

@keyframes anim-shadow {
 to {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 80px 30px;
   opacity: 0;
 }
}

.symbol-input100 {
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #999999;

 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 25px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: 30px;
 pointer-events: none;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}

.input100:focus + .focus-input100 + .symbol-input100 {
 color: #00c6fb;
 padding-left: 23px;
}


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Button ]*/
.container-login100-form-btn {
 width: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}

.login100-form-btn {
 font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
 font-size: 15px;
 line-height: 1.5;
 color: #e0e0e0;

 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-radius: 25px;
 background: #333333;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 0 25px;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
 transition: all 0.4s;

 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.login100-form-btn::before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 border-radius: 25px;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #005bea;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 background: linear-gradient(left, #005bea, #00c6fb);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
 transition: all 0.4s;
 opacity: 0;
}

.login100-form-btn:hover {
 background: transparent;
 color: #fff;
}

.login100-form-btn:hover:before {
 opacity: 1;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Button sign in with ]*/
.btn-face,
.btn-google {
 font-family: Raleway-Bold;
 font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 1.2;

 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 width: calc((100% - 10px) / 2);
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 background-color: #fff;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
 -o-transition: all 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
 transition: all 0.4s;
}


.btn-face {
 color: #3b5998;
}

.btn-face i {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}

.btn-google {
 color: #555555;
}

.btn-google img {
 width: 19px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 1px;
}


.btn-face:hover,
.btn-google:hover {
 border-color: #d33f8d;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------------------
[ Alert validate ]*/

.validate-input {
 position: relative;
}

.alert-validate::before {
 content: attr(data-validate);
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 70%;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid #c80000;
 border-radius: 14px;
 padding: 4px 25px 4px 10px;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 right: 8px;
 pointer-events: none;

 font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
 color: #c80000;
 font-size: 13px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 text-align: left;

 visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;

 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s;
 -o-transition: opacity 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s;
 transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

.alert-validate::after {
 content: "\f06a";
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 color: #c80000;
 font-size: 15px;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
 -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 right: 13px;
}

.alert-validate:hover:before {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
 .alert-validate::before {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
 }
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[ responsive ]*/

@media (max-width: 576px) {
 .wrap-login100 {
   padding-top: 80px;
   padding-left: 15px;
   padding-right: 15px;
 }
}
```

I also wanted to change the color of the button.
I tried with no luck.
In addition, I noticed that if there are two different shades of blue. The upper shade is lighter than the lower shade.
I attached some screenshots.
Please help me to change the background and button colors.

This is blue color in the upper section of the page,
[image]

This is the second blue shade in the lower part of the page,
[image]

Comment: Can you please upload the Html also ?

Comment: Thank you Jithin B. I played with HTML element, and it worked.
Thank you all for your answers :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many background color classes provided by **Bootstrap** such as : ***bg-primary, bg-info, bg-success***...etc. You can overwrite it in you CSS as follow :

```
.bg-info {
     background-color: <YourColor>;
}
```

Comment: I found .bg-infom and I edited to the following:
.bg-info {
     background-color: #ff0000;
}

but the color remained blue.

Comment: don't forget to add this new class to your html element

Answer (score 1):

You can always override bootstrap defaults by adding an additional css, after bootrap and the theme's css. 
I use for example

```
.btn-primary {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #007078;
        border-color: #92CDDC;
    }
```

Other bootstrap classes you may want to override for color consistency are all the *primary classes like 
.bg-primary, .table-primary, .table-primary > th, .table-primary > td, .badge-primary, .text-primary, a.text-primary:focus,a.text-primary:hover

Hope this helps you

Comment: i tried playing around with btn, it worked.
but not like what you mentioned.
I managed to change the text... not the background, but I am still trying.
Your suggestion was helpful

Answer (score 0):

For the background color, try adding the background color property to the body like this;

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, sans-serif;
    background-color: <color of choice>;
}
```

Add the same property to your button and add a color you want. Hope it works.

Comment: As an example, I did that:
background-color: #666666; 

It did not work.

Comment: I also tried the following, background-color: #cc0000;
the color is still blue...
I am wondering, where can i find that particular property so that I change it..

Comment: I had to put !important on the background-color property for this to work.